# cannot get the hidden value on document ready

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I had jquery on button click to show the hidden field's value but I go the "undefined". After the page is load, I checked the page source and the hidden field had value. The hidden field value is set on page load. I simply my code to show the issue as below.

There is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="Include/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript" src="/include/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnID').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(getPackageID());
        });
    });
    function getPackageID() {

        return $('hdPackageID').val();

    }

</script>
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>         
        <asp:Button ID="btnID" runat="server" Text="ID" />
         <asp:HiddenField ID="hdPackageID" runat="server" />
         <div id="dialog-box"/>
    </div>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

The value is set on hidden field on page_load  on code behind on my vb code .

```
_PackageID = Request.QueryString("packageID")
        hdPackageID.Value = _PackageID
```

Would someone tell me how can I get the hidden field's value when the button is clicked.

Comment: How about `$("#hdPackageID").val();`

Comment: @MarkC. thanks. I missed the '#" sign. How can I made your comment as answer on this site?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember to let jQuery know what kind of element you're trying to select. If you're trying to select by `id="some-value"`, it's `$("#some-value").val()`. If you're trying to select elements by class, it's `$(".some-class")`

In your case, a simple `id` identifier is all that you needed: `$("#hdPackageID").val();`